# Combining Access Reports

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a created two access reports.  One is a summary report and the other provides greater detail.  There is a common field for each.  The summary report is always 1 page printed portrait.  The detail report is always printed landscape and can be 1 or more pages.  Currently i need to print each report separately and manually match by the common field (employer number).  The print sort is also differs for both.  The summary report has a sequence number.  The detail report does not and uses the employer number as the sort index.

What i would like to figure out is the ability to print these reports out together.    Summary report and then its related detail report... Summary report and its detail report, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a VBA procedure that will open a recordset to allow you to loop through the employee numbers. The main part of the procedure will look something like this:

```
Set rsEmployees = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset "select EmpNo from Employees order by EmpNo"
Do While Not rsEmployees.EOF
    'Print summary report for this employee
    'Print detailed report for this employee
    rsEmployees.MoveNext
Loop
```

Replace the two commented lines with commands to print the two reports. Depending on whether your EmpNo is numeric or text, these commands will look like either

```
docmd.OpenReport "MainReport", acViewNormal, , "EmpNo = " & rsEmployees(0)
```

or

```
docmd.OpenReport "MainReport", acViewNormal, , "EmpNo = '" & rsEmployees(0) & "'"
```

Hope this helps.